# How would I add a second physical hard drive to proxmox

Tags: partition, proxmox

I installed proxmox on a single 250GB hard drive and I would like to add a second identical hard drive to put more VM's on. I already tried once, and didn't get very far. I added it and formatted it as an ext4, but when I went to use the disk, it said only 8GB was available. That's not quite right. So I did some searching and found that I had to make the device ID 8e for a linux lvm. After I did this, it said I had to restart, so I did... and it wouldn't boot!!!

What did I do wrong? And how do I do it right? (I know I could throw in a RAID card and do a RAID 0, but I'd rather not).

Answer (score 17):

You can either use your new disk to create new storage resources:

- New directory (tree) to store files

  - partition and format your device using your filesystem of choice (ext3/4 and XFS are the most commonly used)
  - mount the FS to, say, /srv (do it manualy with mount command and add it to fstab)
  - create the needed directories with `mkdir /srv/{isos,images,templates,backups,containers}`
  - create the Proxmox storage resources of type `directory` in the web UI.
- LVM volume group to store VMs disks "images" as logical volumes:

  - partition your device and set the LVM (8e) flag
  - create a new physical volume with `pvcreate /dev/<DEVNAME>`
  - create a new volume group with `vgcreate <VGNAME> /dev/<DEVNAME>`
  - create the Proxmox storage resource of type `LVM group` in the web UI

Or you can use it to increase size of the default one:

- LVM physical volume to extend the default `pve-data` LVM logical volume and `/var/lib/vz` filesystem:

  - partition your device and set the LVM (8e) flag
  - create a new physical volume with `pvcreate /dev/<DEVNAME>`
  - extend default VG with `vgextend pve /dev/<DEVNAME>`
  - extend `data` logical volume with `lvextend /dev/mapper/pve-data /dev/<DEVNAME>`
  - verify your FS is clean with `fsck -nv /dev/mapper/pve-data`
  - resize your FS with `resize2fs -F /dev/mapper/pve-data`

Checkout http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Storage_Model

Comment: Is it better to extend pve-data or make a new group? I don't understand the ramifications of either.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you for this clear answer. All the wiki they have kinda sucks as far as CLI or even GUI instructions.

Comment: Hang on though, now at a terminal, "Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/pve-data hmmmmm

Comment: The link is broken!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the page that talks about it:

http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Storage_Model

Comment: The link is broken!

Answer (score 0):

https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Extending_Local_Container_Storage

Use "GNU parted" for partitions > 2TB and partition type "ee" (GPT)