# ProxMox with PERC 5/i RAID 5

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, raid5, dell-perc, proxmox

I recently set up a dell 2950 III with ProxMox. I attached an external hard disk that is used to boot ProxMox and I would like to use the RAID 5 array to store data such as images and disks. How would I go about making a file system and allowing ProxMox to access it?

My previous attempts involve creating a partition and formatting it to be an ext4 filesystem. It appears from ssh to be a 1.8TB volume but when I add it to the ProxMox web interface it shows as 10MB.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is the same issue as http://serverfault.com/questions/423544/how-would-i-add-a-second-physical-hard-drive-to-proxmox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use /etc/fstab to mount your raid volume to /var/lib/vz and whalla! Format you raid volume to whatever your like, EXT4(in RAID 5 is OK), ZFS(only with your raid controller in JBOD mode), whatever, and attach it via the FSTAB.

I did it that way, and it works well for me.

PS: If you already have stuff at /var/lib/vz, move it to the raid volume before you attach and reboot.